# Return a value in transaction method in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

Is it possible to return a value in a transaction method in Hyperledger? such as

```
/**
 * @param {org.n.blockchaindemo.GetCreditScoreUser} GetCreditScoreUser - 
the GetCreditScoreUser transaction
 * @transaction
 */
async function getCreditScoreUser(user) {
  return 0;
}
```

If this is not possible, would this mean that the return value would have to be put as a property in a participant or asset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot 'return' out of a transaction - you would have to set something else up to 'emit' something of value.

To return something from your transaction to a client, you would either use Events (see example [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js#L29), eg. emitting a commodity relationship id)   or use a call-out (see [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out) for code examples.

Note also we have an Improvement proposal to address returning data to the client app which you can track for progress info etc->   https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4165